# code igniter - loading a controller and its data within another controller / view

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I'm a bit confused on including a controller / view within another controller/view. I'm doing the following and getting funny rendering issues:

```
//CONTROLLER About
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pages extends CI_Controller {

public function about(){ //the standalone about page
    $data['about_inner'] = $this->about_inner();
    $this->load->view('pages/about',$data);
}

public function about_inner(){ //this is separate so it can be loaded by the landing page without the html shell around it
    $this->load->model('about_model');
    $data['about'] = $this->about_model->get_content();
    $this->load->view('pages/about-inner',$data);
}

}

//view about.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container about" data-page="about">
    <div class="scroll-container about">
        <?=$about_inner; ?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue I'm getting is that $about_inner does not end up loading inside of the "scroll-container" - it loads and renders before everything else, as shown in the screenshot.

What's the best way to get the about_inner view and all of its associated data to load within the about view? I need all the content `($this->about_model->get_content())` to come from about_inner since it can also be loaded by other pages via ajax.

[image]

SOLUTION

```
   public function about(){ //the standalone about page
        $data['nav'] = $this->load->view('templates/nav', NULL, TRUE);
        $data['about_inner'] = $this->about_inner(true);
        $this->load->view('pages/about',$data);
    }





    public function about_inner($print =false){ //this is separate so it can be loaded by the landing page without the html shell around it
        $this->load->model('about_model');
        $data['about'] = $this->about_model->get_content();
        return $this->load->view('pages/about-inner',$data, $print);
    }

    //HTML

    //view about:

    <div class="container about" data-page="about">
        <?=$nav; ?>
        <div class="scroll-container about">
            <?=$about_inner; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to tell the `about_inner` function to return the data and not print the data. That's the 3rd argument to `function view($template, $data, $return);`

```
$this->load->view('pages/about-inner',$data, true);
```

If you need to do either or, just set a boolean flag as the argument to the function

```
function about_inner($print = false){
    ...
    $this->load->view('pages/about-inner', $data, $print);
}
```

Then when you call the function you can simply pass `true` to the function in order to get it to return the HTML instead of printing the HTML.

```
$this->about_inner(true)
```

Comment: Maybe I'm confused as to how to implement this then - that renders the HTML shell properly, but nothing is output in the <?=$about_inner; ?> variable. So in `about` I am saying `$data['about_inner'] = $this->about_inner();$this->load->view('pages/about',$data);` and in about_inner I'm saying `$data['about'] = $this->about_model->get_content();$this->load->view('pages/about-inner',$data,TRUE);`

Comment: Also - if I tell about_inner not to print the data, then it will no longer work as a standalone method to be called via ajax, right?

Comment: Yeah - it's just not outputting anything in the `<?=$about_inner; ?>` - check the revised code above.

Comment: Ah...I figured it out - in `about_inner` I needed to have `return $this->load->view()` instead of just `$this->load->view()`. Thanks for the rest of the help.

Answer (score 0):

if your JS folder is in root you have to define it with `base_url()` function. So correct all the path in `get_content` method

Ex

```
<script src ="<?php echo base_url() ?>path/to/your/folder/aaa.js" .....
```

And i think you can keep one controller method and remove one.(You can keep `about` and remove `about_inner`)

Comment: Yeah - I can get the about_inner via ajax with no problem as it is coded above, but I just can't render about_inner statically within "about"

Comment: Cz here you passing `$data['about_inner']` and `$data['about']` but in view `about_inner`. So it will interrupt each other . Change view to `about` and check

Comment: Sorry abdulla - I don't understand. Maybe you could show some code?

Comment: no - `$data['about']` is the data from the model used in the `about_inner` controller method, $data[`about_inner`] is a reference to the about_inner method itself. If I change $about_inner to $about - I am just referencing the model data within about_inner

Comment: @mheavers is you view load the page as you expected ??